# Multiple queries with slice in one query in django?

Tags: django

i have this model

```
class Car(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

3 colors, 10 000 records

How can I get 6 cars, two of each color with the maximum prices?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a good question for a job interview, but it is not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can do it. Some simply by one line. But since this is a django tagged question, I'll try to answer it with django ORM.

Break it down to three parts.

1. Get two highest cars from color A
2. Get two highest cars from color B
3. Get two highest cars from color C

`Car.objects.filter(color=A).order_by('-price')[:2]`
`Car.objects.filter(color=B).order_by('-price')[:2]`
`Car.objects.filter(color=C).order_by('-price')[:2]`

You can do this is one query. Ill leave you to it.

Comment: This is the essence. How to combine this queries in one?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: OK, but how to apply slices in (with) Q object?

Comment: I downvoted your answer. Googling the issue tells me that this is really non-trivial. If you know how to do it, your answer stops short of telling us. If you are merely guessing it's possible with query expressions, you may as well be wrong.